# How To Override Register Form FosUser And Choice Fields Filles With Roles SYMFONY2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I followed the documentation to override the register form of the FosUser and I display the roles I want like this. Here is my register form.

```
<?php

namespace My\BlogBundle\Form;
use My\BlogBundle\Entity\User; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class MyRegisterType extends BaseType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
 {
    parent::buildForm($builder ,$options);
    $user = new User();
    $builder
        ->add('roles' ,'choice' ,array('choices'=>$user->getRoles() ) ;

 }

 public function getName()
 {
    return 'my_register_type';
 }
}
```

And here is my User entity.

```
<?php

namespace My\BlogBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* My\BlogBundle\Entity\User
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\BlogBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/
class User  extends BaseUser
{
 /**
  * @var integer $id
  * 
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 protected $id;

 protected $roles=array();




/**
 *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article" ,mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $article;

/**
 *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment" ,mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $comment;

 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->roles=array('searcher' ,'annoucer');
 }

}
```

My issue now is I don't know how to display on that field only the roles I added because I get ROLE_USER with the choices also and when I submit the form I get this error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::setRoles() must be an array, string given, called in /var/www/blog/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 346 and defined in /var/www/blog/vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php line 709
```

Any help would be more than appreciated, thanks. BTW I'm sorry I couldn't add other tags :P

Answer (score 4):

I think you problem is because you are using a `ChoiceField`. A ChoiceField will return only one role (a string type, this id of the role) but the method `setRoles` expect an array. This means you need to either add the option `multiple => true` or change to another type of field like a `Collection` field. Using `multiple` will return an array which will be accepted by `setRoles` and using a `Collection` field will also return an array.

Bottom line, you need to choose a form field that returns an array instead of a single result, a string. You can see all form types [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types)

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello guys i tested it out and unfortunatly thats not what i want i wanna let the user choose his (account type which is his role sementicly  ) searcher/annoucer for a job , any other workaround ?? thanks

Comment: Then you must keep your form type, i.e. `ChoiceField` but will need to override the FOSUserBundle class and create a method named `setRole` that will received a string, the id of the role you wish to set. Then, when adding your type to your form, instead of using `roles`, you use `role` and the form component will call `setRole` with a single single value.

Comment: thanks guys ill just use the built in login/logout and make my register

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue, then i use this line of code in controller to resolve it.

> in your registration form

```
->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'label'    => 'User Type',
                'choices' => array(
                    'ROLE_USER' => 'User',
                    'ROLE_STAFF' => 'Staff',
                    'ROLE_INSTITUTE' => 'Institute',
                ),
                'expanded'   => true,
            ))
```

> and in controller

```
    $role = $form->get('roles')->getData();
    $user->setRoles(array($role));
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```